# Where can I find Test Artifact selector in Android Studio 2.2 ?

Tags: android, android-studio, testing, automated-tests

Some time ago it was possible to show/hide Test Artifact selector [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35708264/5913459).

But for now I cannot find opportunity to do this. So any suggestions?

Here are screenshots from Android Studio.

[Gradle->Instrumental](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pt8rh.png)

[Build variants](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSeT7.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

**Previous to Android 2.0**

Previous to Android 2.0 you had to choose one of the two types from the Test Artifacts setting in the *Build Variants window*. You could only run tests of that type, and would only see tests of that type in the project overview.

[image: Unit Tests selection, before Android Studio 2.0]

*Unit Tests selection, before Android Studio 2.0*

[image: Android Instrumentation Tests selection, before Android Studio 2.0]

*Android Instrumentation Tests selection, before Android Studio 2.0*

**Android Studio 2.0**

Android Studio 2.0, however, has a unified testing view. Now you can view and run both kinds of tests, eliminating the need to choose a test artifact.

[image]

Thanks to *Huyen Tue Dao* for the great [article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/124936/whats-new-android-studio-2-0) about this topic and other more which were difficult to understand at the beginning.