# How to upgrade Android Studio 2.3 to build tools 25 to fix "The SDK Build Tools revision (21.1.2) is too low for project Minimum required is 25.0.0"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Which configuration variables and values should I set where to upgrade to Build Tools 25.0.2?  Following the Android Studio messages has not allowed me to fix my Gradle build scripts to Gradle's satisfaction.

Application working fine in Android Studio 2.2 - repeated builds and deployments were fine.  Upgraded Android Studio to 2.3, now getting errors `The SDK Build Tools revision (21.1.2) is too low for project  Minimum required is "25.0.0"`

I have followed the prompts in the Messages tab to the `build.gradle` of each module of the project and added `buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'` to each as directed, but this has not resolved the issue, and nor has changing to `buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'`.

I have invalidated the cache and re-synched gradle; invalidated the cache and restarted Android Studio; and invalidated the cache, stopped Android Studio, `rm -R`'d the various `build` directories, run a text search for "21." without any hits, and restarted my laptop.  No luck.

(please note that this is not the same as https://github.com/c-h-/android_core; in that question Shyamnath Mallinathan is trying to find out how he can carry on using the 23.0.3 version of Build Tools, whereas I am trying to find out how to upgrade to the most recent version of Build Tools - 25.0.2 at the time I raised this)

Comment: Faced similar issues, was able to resolve by pointing to buildtools - 25 Share your gradle files, main and app should do.

Comment: also you can use following command to get the dependency graph of your application

"gradle dependencies"

Comment: Thanks @Neji - resolved by   1) setting `buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'` in all modules' `build.gradle` files  _and_ 2) adding `compileSdkVersion 25` and `buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'` to the top-level `build.gradle`  - which didn't include it before.   Feels like there was a change to how gradle propagated/resolved the Build Tools version within a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Neji :- I resolved this by

1) running "`gradle dependencies`" to get the dependency graph of my application

2) setting `buildToolsVersion` '25.0.2' in all modules' `build.gradle` files and

3) adding `compileSdkVersion` 25 and `buildToolsVersion` '25.0.2' to the top-level `build.gradle`

Comment: `android` block is not supposed to be in root build.gradle if you're using separate modules.

Comment: Is it not?  Thanks  -  although I'm surprised: I thought that it was there to set the application-wide defaults that could then overridden by each module.  My problems make more sense in that case,  but I would have expected a Gradle error pointing that out to me.  I started my project as a fork of https://github.com/c-h-/android_core, which does have `android` clauses in the top-level `build.gradle`, and no problems until this most recent upgrade.

Comment: Ooooh crap, you're using the `allprojects` block? Wait, `android` block is only available after applying `com.android.application` or `...library` plugin which you should only do in modules.

Comment: yep - I am using 'allprojects'  .   Where's a good place to learn all these if-then-except-otherwise rules for Gradle?

Comment: Thanks Eugen;  https://github.com/c-h-/android_core is from a few years ago, and I get the feeling it is still focused on getting ROS-Java to work, rather than good Android/Gradle practices.

Comment: You just pick these up as you go, you can get useful stuff altogether by following Jake Wharton or Genymotion on Twitter, google "speed gradle build" and follow the tips. I read somewhere to avoid `allprojects` because it disables parallel builds which in turn build decoupled modules faster. I forgot `allprojects` existed :D

Comment: Oh that's just nasty.  per my comment at http://stackoverflow.com/a/35708264/1200764 I really miss Ant's visibility, even though I love the dependency injection with Maven/Gradle.